# Rules for real number in quasar

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I need a textfield for quantity without any decimals

```
   <q-input outlined
               v-model.number="myproducts[index].qty"
               type="number"
               style="max-width: 100px"
               :max-decimals="0"
               :rules="[
                      val => val !== null && val !== '' || 'Please type a number',
                      val => val > 0 && ((val % val) === 0) || 'Please type a real number'
                    ]"
      />
```

I tried using mod option but its  not working. Please help
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed  `type="number"`.
And added `mask`

```
 <q-input
        outlined
        style="max-width: 120px"
        v-model.number="myproducts[index].qty"
        mask="#"
        fill-mask="0"
        reverse-fill-mask
        :rules="[
                val => (val !== null && val !== '' && parseInt(val)!=NaN)|| 'Please type a number',
                val => val > 0  || 'Please type a real number'
                ]"
      />
```

Answer (score -1):

A tricky way to detect real numbers is checking if it includes a point. For example:

```js
val.toString().indexOf('.') < 0
```

So, we may reach this implementation for our Quasar's rule:

```html
<template>
  <q-input
    outlined
    type="number"
    style="max-width: 100px"
    :max-decimals="0"
    :rules="[realNumberRule]"
    v-model.number="myproducts[index].qty"
  />
<template>
<script>
export default {
  methods:{
    realNumberRule(val) {
      if (!val) {
        return 'It is mandatory';
      }
      return val.toString().indexOf('.') < 0 ? true: 'Must be a decimal number';
    }

  }
}
<script>
```

Comment: Its showing error for real number, not for decimal number

Comment: In this case, switch the conditions, please.